# React + Firebase saving issue. Why this Hash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Im saving my data to database, using React, like this:

```
export const matchesInitialCreate = (user, matches) => {

  return (dispatch) => {
    firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${user}/matches`)
      .push(matches)
      .then(() => {
       dispatch({ type: MATCHES_INITIAL_CREATE });

  });
 };
};
```

My matches entity is a simple json with some data, divided into

```
matches:{ groups: {...}, knockout {...}}}
```

Everything looks fine, but when I push it to firebase, it is saved with a hash. Like this:

```
            users/user/matches/CRAZY_HASH/matches/groups
```

But I want that it saves like this:

```
            users/user/matches/groups
```

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [different ways to save data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) to Firebase Realtime Database.

- **Push**: [generates a unique key](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) at the specified reference, and writes the given data under this new child
- **Set**: save data to a specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path
- **Update**: updates lower-level child values of a specified reference

The reason why you see a crazy hash is you are using the `push` method. If you want to set the data directly under `users/{user}/matches/groups`, you must use either `set` or `update`.

```
// Will override everything
firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${user}/matches`).set(matches)

// Will update specific children
firebaseApp.database().ref(`/users/${user}/matches`).update(matches)
```

Comment: Save my life. Thanks Antoine!

Comment: You're welcome Fernando! :) If this is the anwer to your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.